# Duplicating form using JS and changing name data

Tags: php, javascript, forms

If it's possible, I would like a general explanation of how I should go about this so I can try to tackle the problem directly myself. As is, I'm having trouble thinking of a solution.

I'm passing values from a form containing book information (ISBN, price, condition, etc.). It's been working very well with a single book. All of this form information is placed inside a div.

I recently implemented a simple JS 'duplicate' function that duplicates all of the form data in the div so users can add another book, or multiple other books. The problem seems to be that all the name values in the original div that I duplicate aren't changing, or aren't accepting that they should now contain multiple values.

How should I go about making each 'book' have it's own values? Should the names in each input be arrays (e.g. book[0]['price']) and then every time another div is added the JS changes the name (e.g. book[1]['price'])?

I'm asking this because I'm really not sure if that would work, and I'd rather hear a more experienced opinion before changing the (already functional) way in which the form is working. If more information is needed please ask and I'll provide.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/133307/how-to-change-name-attributes-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names that you assign in html forms can be arrays. eg price[]

```
<input type="text" name="price[]">
```

Now if you have multiple form inputs with the name 'price[]', it doesn't matter. In fact this makes it useful.

Now in php you can easily access each name using

```
$_POST['price'][$i] //where $i is 0,1,2,3.....
```

Basically what this does is that it creates an array for 'price' under the $_POST array.
You can easily iterate over $i and get values for other fields too.

This answers your statement "or aren't accepting that they should now contain multiple values."

Comment: I tried this earlier, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. It makes perfect sense but I can't get it...

Comment: You have commented on the other answer "So $_POST['ISBN'][0] would have a value, but $_POST['ISBN'][1] would be empty". SO I think there's some problem with html/js. Is your js adding the inputs for other books inside the original <form>.....</form> tag?

Comment: THANK YOU didn't realize when I would duplicate, it took the original form declaration as a part of the div. That's a big derf, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="book1">
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price1" />
<input type="text" name="isbn[]" id="isbn1" />
</div>
```

Duplicate this and update the IDs only, using js(since each ID should be unique),

```
<div id="book2">
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price2" />
<input type="text" name="isbn[]" id="isbn2" />
</div>
```

Now `$_POST['price']` should give you the array of prices and each corresponding element of isbn should give you the isbn of that book

server side would be like,

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];

foreach( $price as $key => $value ) {
  echo "The price is ".$value." and isbn is ".$isbn[$key];
}
```

This is one way I would go..

Comment: I tried making the name values arrays already, but I didn't change the id of the newly created input items. It didn't work at the time. Is that a make/break change?

Comment: not really.. it becomes more of an issue in the js side only.. wat happened when you tried with array? wat values you received on the server side?

Comment: It would actually work with one book, but would not pull the other values. So $_POST['ISBN'][0] would have a value, but $_POST['ISBN'][1] would be empty. I might need to give it another shot now that I have a clearer head

Comment: Finally figured out I was fudging up with my div positions. Your answer is equally as correct thank you for helping!